# Parse-Server "Object Not Found" for Delete

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I am running parse-server on AWS with the database hosted on mLab.

The app works fine except for Delete requests for objects with a user-specified and global read ACL. I can post an object, but if I try to delete the same object, I get:

> Object Not Found, Code 101

The ACL is set for global read and write only for the user who posted it.  I can delete objects with global read and write.

The app worked perfectly before the migration from Parse and it should work the same, I just don't know why it isn't.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I have the exact same problem with a parse-server hosted by heroku

Comment: No i have not unfortunately @AlekPiasecki

Answer (score 0):

Run `destroy` query with `userMasterKey=true`

Try this: `$row->destroy(true);`